Populate Subplots by looping through time
I am creating a 6 panel subplot with each plot showing a different time step for my data. I am having trouble creating a loop that plots each time into one of the panels. I have been able to produce the 6 plots as well as select the proper times to plot, but having issues trying to figure out how to make both of these work together in a loop. Currently I have:
ax1.contour(thpert_neg.sel(xh = slice(xstart,xend), yh = slice(ystart,yend), time=times[4]), color = 'blue', linewidth = lw, levels = np.arange(-1,-.60,.05))
ax2.contour(thpert_neg.sel(xh = slice(xstart,xend), yh = slice(ystart,yend), time=times[8]), color = 'blue', linewidth = lw, levels = np.arange(-1,-.60,.05))
ax3.contour(thpert_neg.sel(xh = slice(xstart,xend), yh = slice(ystart,yend), time=times[12]), color = 'blue', linewidth = lw, levels = np.arange(-1,-.60,.05))
ax4.contour(thpert_neg.sel(xh = slice(xstart,xend), yh = slice(ystart,yend), time=times[16]), color = 'blue', linewidth = lw, levels = np.arange(-1,-.60,.05))
ax5.contour(thpert_neg.sel(xh = slice(xstart,xend), yh = slice(ystart,yend), time=times[20]), color = 'blue', linewidth = lw, levels = np.arange(-1,-.60,.05))
ax6.contour(thpert_neg.sel(xh = slice(xstart,xend), yh = slice(ystart,yend), time=times[24]), color = 'blue', linewidth = lw, levels = np.arange(-1,-.60,.05))

Which is clearly not great. Here is one of the many iterations of what I have tried to use instead:
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3)
ax1, ax2,ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6 = axs
for tt in range(0,25,4): ### This is for each hour
    this_time = times[tt]
    this_ax = axs
        for axn in axs: 
            plt.contourf(thpert_neg.sel(xh = slice(xstart, xend), zh = slice(zstart, zend), time=this_time))


fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3) gives you an array w/ 6 elements.  You can flatten: axs=axs.flat(), and then you can just address as axs[ii] in the loop, where ii goes from 0 to 5.

I don't understand what you try to do.

It would be sth like: axes = [ax1, ax2, ...], times_idxs = [4, 8, ...], and for ax, t_idx in zip(axes, times_idxs): ...


I have changed something

the method .sel() because I want to show the correct values on the coordinate axes,
no colors="blue"
the range for t, because in your code you have 7 t values ([0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 29, 24]) and only 6 Axes
the levels, do you think that ~1200 lines gives the optimal result?

Eventually I wrote a loop using the zip builtin.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Thpert():

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        x = range(11)
        self.x, self.y = (xy/5-1 for xy in np.meshgrid(x,x))
        # -1 <= x <= +1, -1 <= y <= +1,

    def sel(self, **kw):
        t = kw['time']
        return self.x, self.y, -4.5*t/(self.x+self.y+3+t*self.y**2)

thpert_neg = Thpert()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(10, 5), layout='constrained')

for ax, t in zip(axes.flatten(), range(4, 25, 4)):
    c = ax.contour(*thpert_neg.sel(time=t), levels=np.linspace(-60, -1, 60))
    plt.colorbar(c, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title('T = %0.2d'%t)
plt.show()

